# Save state between closening/opening intro part

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have Eclipse RCP application. My own `IntroPart` extends `org.eclipse.ui.part.IntroPart`.

Through inheritance I got this method:

```
@Override
public void saveState(IMemento memento) {
}
```

[Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_does_a_view_persist_its_state_between_sessions%3F) it is stated that when the workbench is shut down, the method `saveState` is called on all open views. But this is true only if I close my whole application.

What should I do, to save the intro page state before if I close only this page, not the hole application?

Comment: Call the `saveState` method?

Comment: calling `saveState`would be a great idea if you figure out how to obtain the `IMemento` object that is used to persist the state in the workbench

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_does_a_view_persist_its_state_between_sessions?) to the FAQ answers that:

> Another mechanism for persisting view state is the JFace IDialogSettings facility. The advantage of dialog settings over the view save/init mechanism is that you can control when settings are persisted.

This is an example on how to use IDialogSettings to persist the state of an IntroPart when it is closed and how to restore it when it is created. MyIntroPart is an IntroPart that has a `Text` widget. The displayed text is saved when the IntroPart is closed and restored when it is created.

To get the `partClosed` event, MyIntroPart implements IPartListener2 and registers itself with the PartService.

```
private static final String MY_INTRO_SETTINGS = "my_intro_settings";
private static final String MY_INTRO_TEXT_KEY = "my_intro_text";

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    this.text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);

    // try to load the settings
    IDialogSettings settings = Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings();
    IDialogSettings section = settings.getSection(MyIntroPart.MY_INTRO_SETTINGS);
    if (section != null) {
        // set the restored text string in the text widget
        this.text.setText(section.get(MyIntroPart.MY_INTRO_TEXT_KEY));
    }

    // register the part listener
    getIntroSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(this);
}
```

This will restore the text to the text widget.

MyIntroPart implements `partClosed` of IPartListener2 to save dialog settings when the view is closed:

```
@Override
public void partClosed(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    // remove part listener from part service
    getIntroSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().removePartListener(this);

    IDialogSettings settings = Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings();

    // get the section of the text
    IDialogSettings section = settings.getSection(MyIntroPart.MY_INTRO_SETTINGS);

    // if it doesn't exist, create it
    if (section == null) {
        section = settings.addNewSection(MyIntroPart.MY_INTRO_SETTINGS);
    }

    // put text from text field in section
    section.put(MyIntroPart.MY_INTRO_TEXT_KEY, this.text.getText());
}
```

Thanks to fredrik for pointing out that no loading from or saving to a file is required here.

Comment: You can skip the "filename" stuff. Just retrieve the settings from your plug-in activator, use it with get/put and the settings will be persisted when the application exists (when Activator.stop() is called).

Comment: @fredrik Thank you! I thought calling `save` was required here since OP wanted to save after closing the part, not after application exit. But it actually works like expected without using a file. I changed the code.